# Get the columns names of a table by query using node.js and socket.io

Tags: mysql, node.js

as i'm getting the result of the following, if i'll only use the queryResult[i], the output will be:

```
object Object
object Object
object Object
object Object
object Object
object Object
```

as expected
(i have 6 columns in my table)

so what should come after the dot in order to get the names of the columns?

```
var newQuery = 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM `my_data`.my_table;';
socket.emit('new query', newQuery);
var html='';

socket.on('query results', function(queryResult){

    for (i = 0; i < queryResult.length; i++){

        html += '<section id="resultTitle"><a href="#">' + queryResult[i].///HERE/// + '</a></section>';
        $('#searchResults').html(html);

    } 
});
```

Comment: Try a `console.log(JSON.stringify(queryResult[i]))`. It would write your object as a JSON string and you could see the name of the value you want

Comment: it was 'Field' by the way